# Visual Studio displaying errors even if projects is closed or rebuild?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, compiler-errors

I add MySql.dll to my project and I replace all classes of Sql server to Mysql. In source code I dont' have any errors but my project is not building. lots of time I close the solution and I open again but didn't work.

[image: below is an image of my window that there is no errors in code but show errors in errors list]

Comment: Did you try removing the references and re-add the references? It may be due to the path of the dll not correct.

Comment: Try installing it from nuget `Install-Package MySql.Data`

Comment: I install dll from NUget package Manger. All classes of Mysql is accessible in every place. Are you think that references path is still incorrect??

Comment: Try using full name `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection sqlconn = null;`?

Comment: Did you try removing the "bin" and "obj" folders on your project directory?